# Maximizing linear equation with integer

Tags: linear-programming

> If I have a linear equation like
>
> $$ c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + ... + c_nx_n = m \leq M $$
>
> with the constraint $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$ for $0 \le i \le n$,
>   where $M$ and the $c_i$ are constants, and where the $c_i$ are
>   rational, how do I maximize $m$?

A friend suggested looking at the least squares method, which I didn't really understand, or possibly at trying to find the least common multiple of a subset of the $c_i$ values and checking if that divides M, but that's a little more trial-and-error than I'm hoping for.

Note: I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere; I didn't see any solutions that matched this problem but I also didn't really know how to search for it.

Comment: What kind of numbers are the $c_i$? Does your $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$? So your $x_i$ are to be chosen optimal?

Comment: The $c_i$ are rational numbers and $\mathbb{N}$ does include 0. And yes, I want to pick the $x_i$ so that $m$ is as large as possible while still less than $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing your $\mathbb{N}$ does contain the zero, you can model this problem as [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)
$$
\max_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \left\{ c^\top x \mid A x \le b , x \ge 0\right\}
$$
where $A = c^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ and $b = M \in \mathbb{R}^1$.

For an actual calculation, your could try standard software like [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/).

Comment: thanks! and especially thanks for the suggestion for how to actually calculate it. that was my next question :)

Comment: Please note the correction of the program name.

Comment: If you have a smaller problem instance I can run an example.

Comment: I don't have any data right now, sorry. I was actually trying to solve a friend's problem. I will have to ask her for a sample.